# string to byte arrays (using linq or regex)?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm trying to fill two byte[] form a string.

```
string xpto = "{ 0, 0, 5 },{  1, 255, 1 }";
```

It could be done by splitting and parsing.
But I want to avoid lots of code, and at same time learn a clever way of doing this... using C#!

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You can use the BitConverter class to do this.

Comment: For me is not so clear how do you expect the conversion to work for the given example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arrays = Regex.Matches(xpto, @"{([^}]+)}")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value // take group value " 0, 0, 5 "
                                .Split(',') // split into three strings
                                .Select(s => Byte.Parse(s.Trim())) // parse each
                                .ToArray()); // convert to byte array
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be an easy way to do that :

```
string xpto = "{ 0, 0, 5 },{  1, 255, 1 }";
var convertedBytes = Regex.Split(xpto, @"\D+")
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x!="")
    .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by "},{", then split each one by "," and remove what's not necessary.

```
    string xpto = "{ 0, 0, 5 },{  1, 255, 1 }";
    List<byte[]> listOfByteArrs = new List<byte[]>();

    string[] byteArrSplitter = Regex.Split(xpto, "},{");

    foreach (string byteArrString in byteArrSplitter)
    {
        string[] byteSplitter = Regex.Split(byteArrString, ",");
        byte[] byteHolder = new byte[byteSplitter.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < byteSplitter.Count(); i++)
        {
            byteHolder[i] = Convert.ToByte(Regex.Replace(byteSplitter[i].ToString(), @"\{|\}|\s", ""));
        }
        listOfByteArrs.Add(byteHolder);
    }
```

The code is pretty straight forward, split the string into "byte arrays", then split by "," to get each value, clean it up and asign it to a new byte. Then add it to a list, if you want your byte[] listed.

Comment: I actually tested its execution time, and surprisingly my method counted 1354 ticks, while Plexus' counted 14251 ticks. Thought it would be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a parser-based solution (for fun). It should be faster (about 10 ticks on an i7) than the other answers though, but not as maintainable.

```
var p = new Parser();
byte[][] data = p.Parse("{ 0, 0, 5 },{  1, 255, 1 }");


class Parser
{
    char c;
    int i;
    string data;

    private bool next()
    {
        if (i == data.Length) { c = (char)0; return false; }
        else { c = data[i++]; return true; }
    }

    public byte[][] Parse(string data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        if (data.Length == 0) return null;
        i = 0;
        List<List<byte>> result = new List<List<byte>>();
        List<byte> currentList = new List<byte>();
        while (next())
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '{': currentList = new List<byte>(); break;
                case '}': result.Add(currentList);        break;
                default : ParseByte(currentList);         break;
            }
        }
        return result.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToArray();
    }

    private void ParseByte(List<byte> currentList)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(c)) return;
        byte currentByte = 0;
        while (char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            currentByte *= 10;
            currentByte += (byte)(c - '0');
            next();
        }
        currentList.Add(currentByte);
    }
}
```